# Sort the dictionary keys alphabetically and create the new dictionary with sorted keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have dictionary

```
my_dict={'VAR': '0x4225', 'CAR': '0x4100', 'SAR': '0x4005', 'AAR': '0x4220'}
```

I want it sort the keys alphabetically and

```
my_dict_alphabetical_order ={'AAR': '0x4220', 'CAR': '0x4100', 'SAR': '0x4005', 'VAR': '0x4225'}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered data structures. Use a `collections.OrderedDict`, or another ordered structure.

Comment: I got the feeling that the fact that CPython 3.6's dict are ordered as an implementation detail is extremely confusing about what a dictionary is supposed to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) - a dictionary that remembers the order in which the keys were added:

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items()))
OrderedDict([('AAR', '0x4220'), ('CAR', '0x4100'), ('SAR', '0x4005'), ('VAR', '0x4225')])
```

Comment: OrderedDict doesn't return the dict, does it?

Comment: @Amit `OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`. The operation here is a bit tricky: `my_dict.items()` returns an iterator of the (key, value) pairs of the dictionary; `sorted()` sorts these **couples** by alphanumerical order (ie the first value of the couples is compared, then the second), and since the first value is a string, these are sorted by alphanumerical order as well. `sorted` returns an iterable, that the `OrderedDict` constructor takes as parameter to construct the instance. What this line gives you is not a `dict` object, but an `OrderedDict` object.

Comment: To be exact, `OrderedDict` extends `idct`, so what you get *is* a dictionary, but it's more. Anyway, the consequence is that you can use it as a dictionary, and more specifically, you can call its keys like you usually do, with `myOrderedDict['foo']`.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: This answer is rubbish, but check the comments below for actual python knowledge.

IPython "does it" automatically.

```
In [1]: my_dict={'VAR': '0x4225', 'CAR': '0x4100', 'SAR': '0x4005', 'AAR': '0x4220'}

In [2]: my_dict
Out[2]: {'AAR': '0x4220', 'CAR': '0x4100', 'SAR': '0x4005', 'VAR': '0x4225'}
```

The thing is, why would you want to do that with an actual dictionary? The values are meant to be accessed thanks to their keys, not their nonexistant index.

Comment: _"It does it automatically"_ - No, I'm afraid it doesn't. A dictionary is an unordered collection of key value pairs. The dictionaries doesn't sort the keys automatically because dictionary cannot be sorted.

Comment: Not true. A dictionary is unordered.

Comment: That's IPython (or Jupyter) fooling you. They overwrite the way dictionaries are displayed by ["displaying" it in `sorted` order](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/6.1.0/IPython/lib/pretty.py#L606).

Comment: @MSeifert Thank you for clearing up my misunderstanding, I thought this was default behaviour and didn't see what more could be asked for. Leaving this up for educative purposes :)

Comment: I want output to be sorted and stored in dict. 
I know the nature of dictionary that the order of elements while the dictionary was being created is different from the order in which they are actually stored and displayed.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Your help is deeply appreciated. Cheers

Comment: You might want to point out that the answer applies to IPython i.e. *IPython "does it" automatically: [...]*

Comment: @MSeifert Done! Thanks